# Nuget for Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 not available?

Tags: asp.net-core, memory-leaks

We are facing memory leak with ConfigurationRoot. Looking at this thread, it's now been fixed:
https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/861

This requires us to upgrade to Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions/

But, I am not able to locate Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 nuget anywhere. Any idea where I can find this?

Comment: You need a [Framework Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft.NETCore.App` is a metapackage, which references all commonly used library for an .NET Core application. Install a new .NET SDK Runtime on the target system.

The version will still be 3.0.0, but when you run the application it will roll-forward to the newest patch version.

If its an self-contained application (vs. portable application which requires a .NET Core runtime installed on target system), then update the SDK on the build system and recompile your application to cause build system putting the latest .NET Core artefacts in the publish directory.

Comment: Problem is we are not able to upgrade Microsoft. Extension.Configuration as it requires to install Microsoft.netcore.app 3.0.0 version

Comment: Nuget package upgrade fails

Comment: You just need to install the new runtime... assuming you already have an .NET Core 3.0 application. If not, you have to Upgrade your application to .NET Core 3.0., see [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: No, .NET Core is independent of Visual Studio (its just a runtime such as java runtime), it also works with Visual Studio Code and no IDE at all (compiling/running with `dotnet run` in console). But only Visual Studio 2019/Code officially supports .NET Core 3 for development